# Facebook APP Authorizatoin blank page

Tags: facebook, authorization

I'm trying to configure my app for Facebook auth, but when the Facebook authorization popup opens, and credentials and introduced, it simple stays blank.
I configured the Site URL, which is something like "http://a.b.c.d/app", and already configured app domains as "a.b.c.d".
Is this configuration incorrect? Why this blank page?

Thanks!

Comment: And what's the url for that page?

Comment: Hi, the popup URL is this http://pastebin.com/EtfgXbAh (where API_KEY corresponds to my APP ID and MY_DOMAIN is my configured domain, in this case a.b.c.d)